# TeamCity and PHP

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, phpunit

We are considering [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for continuous integration but have projects in both Rails (Rake tests) and PHP (PHPUnit tests).

I'm a bit new to CI - Has anyone setup TeamCity for PHP projects?  If so, is it straight-forward?

Thanks,
Chad

Comment: update: it wasn't hard.  built ant scripts.  where was SO on this one?  jk love the site.

Comment: Chad, you should answer your own question and accept the answer. I just saw this question for the first time, but I would have answered the same thing.

Comment: I just upvoted your question and downvoted your not-an-answer. It would be really nice if you could turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the question answered:

---

Just use ant build scripts, and it'll work with TeamCity.

Comment: To make is disappear from the list and because it's what I'd have suggested: +1

Answer (score 2):

In the high demand market of web development, using CI is very beneficial and almost a requirement (now a days).

We use TeamCity, YouTrack, Perforce and PHP Maven to build, package and deploy our web applications. The setup is as follows:

1. Once developed, code is commited to the Perforce repository main folder for the app
2. TeamCity is configured to check this folder for changes and build each time changes are found (see configuring TeamCity)
3. Once development has reached a point where it's ready to be deployed, we integrate the main branch with the release branch
4. TeamCity is configured to check the release branch for changes and deploy via FTP to the server
5. Cron jobs are running on the app to deploy new releases to a QA branch
6. Once changes and functionality is verified, the status of the QA deployment is set to "deploy"
7. Another Cron job is running looking for new QA releases that are ready to be deployed. Once found, it extracts the package into the live folder

In this case, our PROD and QA folders are on the same server. Alternatively, you can have multiple TeamCity build configurations that push the app to different servers (or use a teamcity to define the environment variable).

Also, when we close tickets/issues in YouTrack, we can pull the build info from TeamCity as they interact with each other.

Links:

Configuring TeamCity, Maven for PHP for Joomla continuous build:
http://www.waltercedric.com/joomla-mainmenu-247/continuous-build/1552-configuring-teamcity-maven-for-php-for-joomla-continuous-build.html

Answer (score 2):

We are using TeamCity to deploy a number of PHP sites -- static, Wordpress and Drupal shortly.

We use the [Deployer plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) to sftp files to the appropriate server and then a script to rsync the files to the right place and to setup apache. Works very, very well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fresh article from JetBrains on how to setup TeamCity with PHP:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/01/continuous-integration-for-php-using-teamcity/